# Angular pagination is not throwing error - is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection<unknown>'

Tags: html, angular, pagination

I am using Angular pagination. I am getting below error. I am not sure what is the issue here.

I installed - import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
and add to the imports

I need help to solve this error. Thank you

```
Argument of type 'Highway[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection<unknown>'.
```

Code

```
<tr
                  *ngFor="
                    let highway of highways
                      | paginate
                        : {
                            itemsPerPage: 10,
                            currentPage: page,
                            totalItems: totalRecords
                          }
                  "
                ></tr>
        <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

.ts file

```
export class HighwaysPageComponent implements OnInit {
  highways?: Highway[];
  favoritesList?: FavoriteDetails[];
  totalRecords: number = 10;
  page: number = 1;
```

Comment: highways: Highway[]=[];

Comment: Thanks, I see all the items, it should display 10 records per page. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you pass in the parameters? The parameters are 10 and should return 10

Comment: I can see `.ngx-pagination` in developer tools. But when I add in scss `.ngx-pagination {
  background-color: red;
}
` why does it not work?

Comment: Got the same problems. Will appreciate some help on how you resolved yours